# Pandas - Distinct list of values from Pandas column's regex groups

Tags: regex, python-3.x, pandas

I have the first lines of all English language Wikipedia articles in a Pandas dataframe and I would like to extract the languages mentioned in brackets into a distinct list.

For example:

```
text
A cat (Afrikaans: kat, German: katze) is an animal.
This line does not contain anything.
A dog (Afrikaans: hond, German: hund, Some language: dog) is an animal.
```

I would like a list with `['Afrikaans', 'German', 'Some language']`.

Also not sure how to specify a unicode supporting regex for something like `df.text.str.extract(r'(\w+):')`

Anyone have any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Do you need to support unicode or do you just need the output you've listed from your input? Your example doesn't make it clear.

Comment: I'm assuming lots of language names would have funny characters in them, so basically grab anything before the `:` including unicode characters and spaces.

Comment: Python3 supports unicode, so you could be explicit and enumerate the possibilities. Alternatively, you could implement your logic of "grab anything before the colon", after a comma, and between the parentheses

Comment: With regex you normally have to say something like `re.UNICODE`, I'm saying I'm not sure how to do that with Pandas

Comment: Does the `flags` argument in `Series.str.extract` not work? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html

Comment: Yeah thanks that will do the trick.

Comment: `\w` in Python 3.x `re` is Unicode-aware by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my suggestion:

1. extract text in parentheses as a column
2. extractall capitalized words from column in 1, grouped to a list
3. flatten lists from column in 2 and get the distincts

Here goes:

```
text = \
["A cat (Afrikaans: kat, German: katze) is an animal.", 
"A dog (Afrikaans: hond, German: hund, Some language: dog) is an animal."]

df = pd.DataFrame(text, columns=['text'])
df['in_parentheses'] = df['text'].str.extract("\(([^)]+)\)")
df['languages'] = df['in_parentheses'].str.extractall("([A-Z]\w+)").groupby(level=0)[0].apply(list)

set(sum(df['languages'], []))
```

got:

```
{'Afrikaans', 'German', 'Some'}
```